# How to save some Polars dfs into one file for partial data request was avaliable

Tags: dataframe, python-polars

I want to save some Polars dataframes into one file, and next I want to request data from file with filter by timestamp (datetime) column. I don't need to take all the file in memory, but only filtered part.

I see, Polars API list has Feather/IPC and Parquet files that can do it in a theory, but I don't know how to read this files in Polars with a filter by data.

Before for Pandas I used hdf5 format and it was very clear, but I have not expirience with that new formats for me. Maybe you can help me how to make it most effective.

Comment: You can use [`.scan_parquet()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/howcani/io/parquet.html#scan) and the [Lazy API](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/quickstart/intro.html#lazy-quick-start)

Comment: I can't test it because I can't append data into a file. Code `df.write_parquet("path.parquet")` is rewriting it. How I can do it?

Comment: Usually you can't or don't want to as parquet files are optimized around the entire data set with row groups and compression.  That being said, it isn't impossible but you have to use pyarrow.  You can convert your polars df to a pyarrow table then use the pyarrow parquet writer.  https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.ParquetWriter.html

Comment: Thank you! Now I convert polars df to pandas df and write it to parquet with fastparquet..